# Is it possible to overfit on test set but not validation set?

Tags: neural-networks, overfitting

I was recently building a DL project and I followed the standard procedure to split the training set into train/val set. Training loss and validation loss decreased smoothly however the model seemed to overfit on test set, test loss plateaued after some epochs.
So, is it possible that my model overfit on test set even validation set doesn't indicate this? Or my model just reaches its capacity?

Comment: "Overfit" in what sense? Are you using held-out test set, that is used only once to evaluate the final model?

Comment: @Tim Sorry to  be imprecise, during training both training and validation loss goes down while the held out test set loss plateaus. Is it kind of overfitting?

Comment: Say that you have 3 samples in train set, 2 in validation set and 1 in test set. You trained and tuned the model to get 66% accuracy on train set, 50% on validation set and 100% on held-out test set. Are you overfitting to test set? No, you’re just lucky.